# Need to find the most reoccurring length, to then find the line which isn't the same length as the rest

Tags: python, macos, count, line

I have a program which scans a file, i need it to find the most reoccurring length of a line to then find the line which isn't the same length as the rest...any tips?

I have a feeling i need to completely change my first if statement.

Here is what i have so far...

```
import sys
import os 
import schedule
import time


#Using schedule, a continuous loop running every 1 second will monitor the folder "filedrop"
#defining the "job" that will be done
def job():
#Find any file in the folder "filedrop" with a .txt then scan it
    for file in os.listdir("/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop/"):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
        #open the file and check to see if it empty
        #if the file is empty it will be moved to the failure folder with a message why
        #if the file has contents the scanning will continue
            with open(file) as f:
                flenme = os.path.basename(file)         #gets the file name for later
                cnt= os.stat(file).st_size              #counts the elements in the file
                try:
                    if cnt > 0:
                        fle = [line.strip() for line in f]          #strips the \n
                        min_char = (min(fle, key = len))            #finds min amount of character
                        max_char = (max(fle, key = len))            #finds max amount of character
                        length_max = len(max_char)                  #converts to numbers to compare lengths
                        length_min = len(min_char)

                        #moving files based on is all records are the same length or not
                        if length_max == length_min:   
                            os.rename("/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop/{0}".format(flenme) ,"/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop/Success/{0}".format(flenme))

                        else:
                            os.rename("/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop/{0}".format(flenme) ,"/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop/Failure/{0}".format(flenme))     
                            os.chdir("/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop/Failure")  #change directory to add to the failed_file document    
                            FldFle= open("failed_files.txt","a")
                            FldFle.write('--"%s" was moved to the "Failure" folder.\n' % (flenme));
                            FldFle.close()
                            os.chdir("/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop")
                    else:
                        os.rename("/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop/{0}".format(flenme) ,"/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop/Failure/{0}".format(flenme))
                        os.chdir("/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop/Failure")      #change directory to add to the failed_file document    
                        FldFle= open("failed_files.txt","a")
                        FldFle.write('--"%s" was moved to the "Failure" folder because it was an empty file.\n' % (flenme));
                        FldFle.close()
                        os.chdir("/Users/justinstarkman/Desktop/Filedrop")

                except :
                    print 'ERROR'
#the program will check the folder for a new file ever 1 second
schedule.every(1).seconds.do(job)   



while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should provide a minimal example, an input and the desired output

Comment: the file i will input is a .txt, the process will scare the file to see if all the lengths of the lines are the same, if they are the file is moved to a success folder...if not it is moved to a failure folder and a string is added to a .txt file saying which line isn't the same length as the rest

Answer (score 0):

For each file you can do the following:

```
import collections

line_lengths = [len(line.strip()) for line in f]

# most common length
mcl = collections.Counter(line_lengths).most_common(1)[0][0]

# indexes_of_other_length_lines 
idx = [n for n, v in enumerate(line_lengths) if v != mcl]
```

This should be everything you need to see if the file is valid (`len(idx) == 0`) and what are the lines of other lengths

Comment: So would this replace my first if statement?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to adapt the code to your needs

Comment: I tried using it but it says all lines are 1, even if there is more than one word on the line, also if theres only one word on each line and one is longer than the other it still prints 1 for all lines. Does this method count the words on each line or the total amount of characters on each line?

Comment: I'm sorry this is not working for you. [Here](https://ideone.com/68rTGb) you can find a basic working example of my snippet

Comment: [5, 5, 5, 8]
Most common length: 5
indexes_of_other_length_lines: [3]

Comment: Isn't this correct? If not you should edit your question and add example input and desired output

Comment: I was wondering what the [0][0] mean in the .most_common(1)[0][0], i know what the (1) means but i am a little lost on the [0][0], also what exactly the n for n means..thank you

Comment: the [most_common](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method of `Counter` returns a list of the most common elements and their counts, in tuples. so the first `[0]` is to get the first tuple from the list. the second `[0]` to get the first element of such tuple. Since each tuple is in the form (key, count), with the index `0` you get the key only, which in your case is a length

Comment: Thank and then in idx:n for n is this just a way to run through the tuple?

Comment: Sort of. It's called *list comprehension* and it is used to loop on an iterable and build a new list